# Keyboard is not working in GRUB menu

Tags: boot, 14.04, grub2, keyboard

My **Laptop** key is not working in GRUB menu. I *don't* have a dual-boot or USB keyboard attached.

I have searched : [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459243/arrow-keys-not-working-in-grub) , [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53353/cant-use-my-new-logitech-k750-when-booting-grub-in-ubuntu-11-04?lq=1) or [here](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=29529) but all the options are either for Dual boot system or for external usb [PS/2] keyboards but my system is a Laptop. ***(*so this question is not a duplicate!)***

When my system starts it automatically shows GRUB (Advance Recovery) menu but no keys are working so how do I enter? + the FAN rotates heavily and after a minute my laptop shuts down automatically.

What do I do, please help?

**Info** : *Sony Vaio C series*, *Ubuntu 14.04 x64 updated*

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer myself! If anyone is facing the same problem then :-

1. Use Page UP / Page Down to select any option.
2. In my case it went to the last option in the list ( - Memory check)
3. I opted for Memory Check and used 'Esc' to return to the GRUB menu
4. Now the Up/Down arror key started working.
5. PROBLEM SOLVED

My actual problem was ATI graphics card driver so I followed the amazing instruction in **askubuntu** [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)